# Why am I getting a casting error in .NET 7 after using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, .net-7.0

Is reflection and casting different in .NET 7 vs .NET Framework? I'm porting a project and getting this casting error after moving the code over. The wierd thing is this class implements that interface. This code works in .NET 4.x.

```
    foreach (Assembly pluginAssembly in pluginAssemblies)
    {
        try
        {
            // Look for class(s) with our interface and construct them
            foreach (var type in pluginAssembly.GetTypes())
            {
                Type iDesigner = type.GetInterface(typeof(IFireworksDesigner).FullName);
                if (iDesigner != null)
                {
                    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type); // creates an object 
                    IFireworksDesigner designer  = (IFireworksDesigner)instance; // throws an exception
                    // do stuff
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //Something really bad must have happened. 
            MessageBox.Show("Fatal error reflecting plugins in assembly '" + pluginAssembly.FullName + "'.\r\n" +
                "The error message is:\r\n\r\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Update: I've made a sample repos at https://github.com/chrpai/reflection

With a FW48 EXE calling .NET Standard 2.0 it works.
With a Core7 EXE calling either a .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET 7 DLL it fails.

Comment: `pluginAssembly.GetTypes()` will return non-constructable types, such as `interface` types and `abstract class` types - and `class` types without parameterless constructors. You need to check that `var type` _can_ be constructed first.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it did construct.  Activator.CreateInstance(type) returns an object and I can see the expected properties on it in the debugger.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: What is the exact exception being thrown? What is its type, message, and call-stack?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'FireworksFramework.FireworksPlugin' to type 'FireworksFramework.Interfaces.IFireworksDesigner'   This is a 12 y/o FOSS project that I'm exploring moving to .NET 7. The code is on GitHub if your willing to pull it down and take a look. https://github.com/iswix-llc/fireworkscore/tree/dev

Comment: This repos is .net 4 before conversion and it's working. https://github.com/iswix-llc/fireworks/tree/master/

Comment: The assemblies that you're loading must reference the exact same assembly as the assembly containing `IFireworksDesigner` - are they perhaps referencing a .NET Framework version of the assembly instead of the .NET Standard/.NET 7+ version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249847/discussion-between-christopher-painter-and-dai).

Comment: Can you perhaps try changing your if statement to `if (typeof(IFireworksDesigner).IsAssignableFrom(type))`?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Linqpad 7 targeting .NET 6. `type.GetInterface(typeof(IFireworksDesigner).FullName)` always returns `null`, weird...

Comment: I tried it in .NET Fiddle with the same results: https://dotnetfiddle.net/q8q4Pi - @ProgrammingLlama any idea? I'm stumped too

Comment: @Dai Honestly, no. If anything was going to work, you'd think the `AssemblyQualifiedName` would, but it's clearly not.

Comment: Interestingly, using `.Name` instead of `.AssemblyQualifiedName` or `.FullName` seems to work.  [Modified fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7vkAhd).

Comment: I never liked the `Type.GetInterface(String)` method: ["stringly-typed" APIs are not fun](https://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped). (Next on my list of bad APIs: all the `Object DataSource` properties in WinForms/WPF...)

Comment: If I use  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes() instead of Assembly.LoadFile(file.FullName).GetTypes() it works. I need to use LoadFile though because I need to scan the directory for designers provided by other dlls/exe.

Comment: The classes may implement the interface with the same name but different assembly names, so try to rebuild these plugins with the latest library.

Comment: @shingo all the classes are in the same library.

Comment: Whoop I got it!  Trying to simply cast to itself and not it's interface gave me a more useful error message that led me to here. Still not sure why this works in .NET Framework but not .NET but I'll take it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29978888/type-a-dll-cannot-be-cast-to-type-b-dll-type-a-originates-from-in-the-context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the reason, the conclusion is the interface the class implemented and the interface you try to cast to exist in different `AssemblyLoadContext`s, so it fails.

---

#### Details

[The documentation of `LoadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile?view=net-7.0) says:

> LoadFile does not load files into the load-from context

That means `LoadFile` will load an assembly into a new context, [the source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/Assembly.cs,250) also verifies this.

```
AssemblyLoadContext alc = new IndividualAssemblyLoadContext($"Assembly.LoadFile({normalizedPath})");
result = alc.LoadFromAssemblyPath(normalizedPath);
```

After you load *LibCore.dll* by `LoadFile`, there are 2 `AssemblyLoadContext`s exist in the program, both of them have an interface `IPlugin` with the same name and same assembly name. So the code `type.GetInterface(typeof(IPlugin).FullName)` even using `AssemblyQualifiedName` is not able to distinguish between different contexts.

Using the following code to verify.

```
// IndividualAssemblyLoadContext #2
Console.WriteLine(AssemblyLoadContext.GetLoadContext(iDesigner.Assembly));
// DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0
Console.WriteLine(AssemblyLoadContext.GetLoadContext(typeof(IPlugin).Assembly));
```

---

#### Solution 1

Use `LoadFrom` instead of `LoadFile`. `LoadFrom` loads an assembly into load-from context, so the interface can be shared.

```
pluginAssemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFrom(file));
```

#### Solution 2

Use an individal core library, for example you can have 3 projects.

```
ConsoleCoreCore.exe

LibCore.dll
    public interface IPlugin
    public class Server

Lib1.dll
    public class LibStandardPlugin : IPlugin
```

Both *Lib1.dll* and *ConsoleCoreCore.exe* refer to *LibCore.dll*

```
ConsoleCoreCore.exe -> LibCore.dll <- Lib1.dll
```

Now if you load *Lib1.dll* from *LibCore.dll* by `LoadFile`, *Lib1.dll* will be loaded into an individal context, but its `IPlugin` interface is still the one from *LibCore.dll*.

```
// IndividualAssemblyLoadContext #1
Console.WriteLine(AssemblyLoadContext.GetLoadContext(type.Assembly));
// DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0
Console.WriteLine(AssemblyLoadContext.GetLoadContext(iDesigner.Assembly));
// DefaultAssemblyLoadContext #0
Console.WriteLine(AssemblyLoadContext.GetLoadContext(typeof(IPlugin).Assembly));
```